# Can't find element with Selenium even though I know the element exists

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer-11

Okay, so I'm trying to find

```
<span class="totalcount">171</span>
```

on https://boston.craigslist.org/search/sss?query=food+stamps&sort=rel&search_distance=200&postal=01841
with

```
pagelement = driver.find_element_by_class_name('totalcount')
```

but for some reason I keep getting the following error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to find element with css selector == .totalcount
```

For reference, I'm using internet explorer 11 with Selenium because my boss requested I switch over to that from Firefox. Could that be what is causing the problem? (Before someone asks, I know it isn't because the page hasn't loaded yet, I added a wait specifically to deal with that.)

Comment: Have you inspected the live DOM in Internet Explorer? Why do you switch from Firefox to IE11 anyway?

Comment: can you please share the source html code

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem because my boss requested me to.

Comment: @MoeGhafari Sure. It's https://boston.craigslist.org/search/sss?query=food+stamps&sort=rel&search_distance=200&postal=01841 (I work for the USDA, I'm trying to make a scraper that'll automatically report people trying to sell food stamps on craigslist.)

Comment: I didn't find any `171` on the [link](https://boston.craigslist.org/search/sss?query=food+stamps&sort=rel&search_distance=200&postal=01841) but I did find `172` as in `1 - 120  / 172` are you looking for that?

Comment: Are you waiting for the page to finish rendering before looking for the item? have you tried using one of the wait functions to wait for the element to be visible?

Comment: @DebanjanB Yeah, that's it. The number changes as new listings are posted obviously.

Comment: @BryanOakley I literally stated in my question that I put in a wait so that it wouldn't check before the page had loaded so no-one would ask me that lol.

Comment: Please post all the relevant code you are using. You state that you are using a wait but that code is not posted here. Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

I did work for me, but im using find_elements as there are more than one element with the same locator strategy and also using chrome

not sure if it will help you, but you can use the below code for a better approach

**Update:** Tired with IE and its working

```
from selenium.webdriver import Ie

driver = Ie('path to IE driver')
driver.get('https://boston.craigslist.org/search/sss?
query=food+stamps&sort=rel&search_distance=200&postal=01841')

total_count = [x.text for x in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('totalcount')]
print(total_count)

 ['170', '170']
```

Comment: Questions is regarding IE not chrome

Comment: It didn't seem to work for me. I am now getting an error saying "OSError: [WinError 740] The requested operation requires elevation". Does this mean I need to go set the driver to run as an administrator?

Comment: Try that. I'm sorry I have never faced that issue, may be someone else can help you with that. But the code works in my system and I'm the administrator of my system